# Montserrat.sty nowhere to be found

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I'm trying to use the Montserrat font with pdflatex, but keep getting the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `montserrat.sty' not found.
```

Both **texlive-fonts-recommended** and **texlive-fonts-extra** are installed and up-to-date. Searching for the file with **apt-file search** comes up empty.

I use **Linux Mint 18.3**, tex version is **pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)**.

The example is tried is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[defaultfam,tabular,lining]{montserrat}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Am I missing something?

Many thanks in advance!

Nathan

Comment: It isn't in TL15, you need at least TL16 or you must install in manually from ctan.